# Remove add to cart button from shortcode in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am implementing a shop that only allows logged in users to view the add to cart buttons.

I have successfully hidden most of them with the following code:

```
function thread_remove_loop_button(){
    if(!is_user_logged_in() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }
}
add_action('init','thread_remove_loop_button');
```

However, there are still some showing in the New Products & Best seller widgets. Looking at the code, I can see these are calling the shortcode

```
do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.$product->id.'"]');
```

What is the best way to amend these so the add to cart button only shows for logged in users. Obviously in the template I can do something along the lines of

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
    echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.$product->id.'"]');
}
```

but it seems like there should be a better way? Along the lines of a hook or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('init', 'bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in');

function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );  
 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 31 );
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 11 );
}
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

put this in your plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
it will hide the price and add to cart button and print a statement login to see price

Answer (score 0):

The add to cart template function is pluggable, meaning that if you define a function in your theme with the same name it will override that of WooCommerce.

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $args = array() ) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        wc_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' , $args );
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hook which not affect other code.

```
add_action('init', 'hide_add_cart_not_logged_in');

function hide_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {       
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
 }
}
```

that only allows logged in users to view the add to cart button.

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html